# Unable to view chart in Google Pie chart extension in qlikview

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, qlikview

I am using the following Google Chart extension and the code is given below :

```
Qva.LoadScript("http://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=loadGoogleCoreChart", function () {
      });

    function loadGoogleCoreChart() {
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['corechart'],
    callback: googleCoreChartLoaded
});
}

function googleCoreChartLoaded() {
Qva.AddExtension('GooglePieChart', function () {

    //Declaring a two dimensional array (an array of arrays)
    var row = new Array(this.Data.Rows.length + 1);
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.Data.Rows.length; i++) {
        row[i] = new Array(2);
    }

    //Getting the data from QlikView
    for (var j = 1; j <= this.Data.Rows.length; j++) {
        row[j][0] = this.Data.Rows[j - 1][0].text;

        var temp = this.Data.Rows[j - 1][1].text;
        row[j][1] = Number(temp);
    }

    //Changing the array to a data table
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(row);

    //Instantiating and drawing the chart
    new google.visualization.PieChart(this.Element).draw(data, { chartArea: 
   { left: 20, top: 20, width: "100%", height: "100%"} });
});
   }
```

After I have loaded a sample data using the script editor and the select a dimension in the extension I am unable to see the chart. Can anyone please help me with what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is the function which worked:

```
Qva.LoadScript("http://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=loadGoogleCoreChart", function () {
});

  function loadGoogleCoreChart() {
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['corechart'],
    callback: googleCoreChartLoaded
});
}

function googleCoreChartLoaded() {

Qva.AddExtension('QlikView/Examples/GooglePieChart', function () {

    var html = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js\"></script>"; 
    html += "<div id=\"piechart\" style=\"width: 900px; height: 500px;\"></div>";

    this.Element.innerHTML = html;
    this.Element.innerHTML = "<h1>Testing Extension</h1>"; 

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
   };
    new google.visualization.PieChart(this.Element).draw(data, { chartArea: { left: 20, top: 20, width: "100%", height: "100%"} });
});
 }
```

Although, here I have the data present in the function itself. I still have to figure out how to take input from Qlikview, I urge anyone who knows the trick to help me out.